# document.getElementbyId is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-11

Am trying to fetch the entire div content and displaying in a alert message using document.getElementById. It is working fine in IE 8 & 9, but not in IE 10 & 11.

Below is the code snippet which am using.

```
<body>
  <div id="oDiv1"><input type="text" ></div>
  <div id="oDiv2">Div #2</div>
  <div id="oDiv3">Div #3</div>
  <input type="button" value="Show First DIV Content" onclick="fnGetId()">
</body>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function fnGetId() {
             var oVDiv=document.getElementById("oDiv1").innerHTML;
             alert(oVDiv);    
    }
</script>
```

Am entering some text in that textbox. In IE 8 & 9 its taking the oDiv1 content along with the text which I entered. Like below

```
<input type="text" value="aaa">
```

But in IE 10 & 11, its taking the input tag but not the value which I entered.

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I get the content along with the values which I entered in IE11?

Comment: You aren't, IE 10 and 11 are standards compliant. Entering a value in the text input should not change the value *attribute*, which reflects the default value in the markup, it changes the value *property*. So what you see in the innerHTML is the value of the value attribute, not value of the value property.

Comment: Have you check this website? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx as per their doc you are using standards compliments

Answer (score 4):

Because you are not getting the right value and you are not getting the right element. Here is a hacky solution.

```
var oVDiv=document.getElementById("oDiv1").children[0].value;
```

A better pattern would be to create a real form, and serialize the form values on *submit*.

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k68um4u0/)

Comment: Thats not necessarily true. If he wants to do form validation then he needs to be able to check the variables dynamically.

Comment: @Kamran224 If validation fails, then return `false` at the submit event handler, or invoke `preventDefault`

Comment: @self children[0].value is ok when I have one input tag in that div. But if there is two more input tags and select tags in that div, then this will work?

Comment: @Vignesh It will work, but it will only get the first element. You can iterate over the array and get all values, but your going to have to check the types of elements they are in order to get the proper value, especially for a `<select>` box. I'd go with my advice on using a real form to get the job done instead of taking the long way.

Comment: @self But its taking only the values from the textbox. I need to print the entire html inside that div along with the value in the value attribute.

Comment: You need the literal HTML inside that `div`?